# Extract text from pdf file with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

```
import PdfReader;
import PdfTextExtractor;

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(data.getBinaryStream());                       
PdfTextExtractor pdfTE=null;

try{
      pdfTE = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);
      noOfPages=reader.getNumberOfPages();                              
      int page = 1;
      System.out.println("output2:" + pdfTE.getTextFromPage(page));
}
catch (Exception ex) { 
      raiseError("Cannot read pdf file");
}
```

I want to get the text from the pdf file but sometimes it works and sometimes I get the error `Cannot read pdf file`. No images etc.. just simple text. I use an older iText Version (2.1.4).

Comment: i got error: 7781.312800.42850 is not valid number - java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points.

Comment: i wonder if it's because of the pdf file i upload is not correct pdf format?  Because when i upload majority of other pdf files it works.

Comment: You mention that your itext version is a 2.x version. Back then itext text extraction essentially was merely a proof of concept, not ready for production use. But indeed, text from broken pdfs in particular is likely to fail with it. But as you do not share the pdf in question, it is hard to tell...

Comment: To add on @mkl's comment: try again with iText 5.5.10, which was released last week, or with iText 7.0.1, which was released last month. If you still can't get it to work, upload your pdf to a file sharing service like Dropbox and add the link to your question.

Comment: thanks for the replies.  I believe this pdf is a broken pdf since when i tried other pdfs it works.  Regards to newer iText ie 5.5.10 do i have to pay for the license or they expect you provide our source code?

Comment: iText5 and 7 are licensed under AGPL, so for a commercial product you can either turn your entire project into AGPL(and thus make the source code publicly available), or purchase a license.